# Best way to generate strings

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to generate list of all strings of the `abcd1234`. Needless to say, `abcd` would loop through all alphabets `a` to `z` (4 times) and `1234` would loop through 0 to 9 (4 times). All these strings I am storing in a text file. As a second wish, I would like to have this program to have a **resume** feature. i.e. if the program is stopped, then it should start from the where it was left off.

Via brute-force method (i.e. by running 8 loops), I am able to achieve the first part. (Code below). I am aware that this is *the worst* strategy. Any thoughts on the improvements?

For the second part, I through of picking the last line of the output file and then pick each character. However in my method, I am missing out many strings. I know where the bug (in my thinking/method) is, but I am not able to rectify it. Any kind of help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile=$1

if [ ! -f $outfile ]
then
    echo "aaaa0000" > $outfile
fi

lastword=$(tail -1 $outfile)
a_beg=${lastword:0:1}
b_beg=${lastword:1:1}
c_beg=${lastword:2:1}
d_beg=${lastword:3:1}
i_beg=${lastword:4:1}
j_beg=${lastword:5:1}
k_beg=${lastword:6:1}
l_beg=${lastword:7:1}

# echo $a_beg
# echo $b_beg
# echo $c_beg
# echo $d_beg
# echo $i_beg
# echo $j_beg
# echo $k_beg
# echo $l_beg
# echo ""
echo "$a_beg$b_beg$c_beg$d_beg$i_beg$j_beg$k_beg$l_beg"

## This removes the $lastword, as the following loop repeats it!
sed -i '$ d' $outfile


for a in $(eval echo {$a_beg..z})
do
    for b in $(eval echo {$b_beg..z})
    do
        for c in $(eval echo {$c_beg..z})
        do
            for d in $(eval echo {$d_beg..z})
            do
                for i in $(eval echo {$i_beg..9})
                do
                    for j in $(eval echo {$j_beg..9})
                    do
                        for k in $(eval echo {$k_beg..9})
                        do
                            for l in $(eval echo {$l_beg..9})
                            do
                                echo "$a$b$c$d$i$j$k$l" >> $outfile
                            done
            done
                    done
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: An interpreted shell is probably not the best way to do *anything* 4.5 billion times. What are you going to do with these strings anyway?

Comment: I have another program that generates and processes strings. The program however generates all possible strings of given length. However I need to process only above mentioned pattern. SO the number of inputs reduces from 36^8 to 26^4 x 10^4. The plan s to give this file as an input to the other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I can answer first part of your question. The second part seems little complicated :-(.

For the first part, instead of running these loops, you can use GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) utility.

The following command should do the job:

```
parallel echo ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} ::: {a..z} ::: {0..9} ::: {0..9} ::: {0..9} ::: {0..9} > /tmp/a
```

Hope this helps!

-- Mike

Comment: This looks much better solution, however it appears that its too slow! Did some trial run on strings of the type `aa99`, the loops (my code) takes about 3.22 seconds, whereas `parallel` took 1 minute 29 sec.